# Alternative to DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql, group-by, bigdata

I have the following table (`table1`):

```
f_name   | email
---------|---------------------
john     | john123@hotmail.com
peter    | peter456@gmail.com
johnny   | john123@hotmail.com
peter8   | peter456@gmail.com  
...
```

I would like to add a `Group` number for the same email value column:

```
f_name   | email               |Group |
---------|---------------------|------|
john     | john123@hotmail.com | 1    |
peter    | peter456@gmail.com  | 2    | 
johnny   | john123@hotmail.com | 1    |
peter8   | peter456@gmail.com  | 2    | 
...
```

I use the following:

```
SELECT
    email,
    s_index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [email] ORDER BY [email]),
    t_index = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [email])
FROM dbo.table1
```

Is it the best way to do it for big data in Oracle? How can it be done in Impala?

Comment: If these functions do what you want, then they are the best way to do it.  I believe Impala supports them as well.

Comment: Do you have performence issues?

Comment: I think the attached code is not 100% correct. I would like to compare it to alternative way. Afterwards, I'll check for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe much to slow, and maybe not applicable; but if you're looking for an alternative to dense_rank()...

If your table has - besides `f_name` and `email` - some unique id, then one could take the minimal id of each `email`-group as a value for the `groupId`. Of course, the groupId must have the same type as the id, and it should not matter that the values for `groupId` are not continuous, i.e. they will have gaps:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" int, "f_name" varchar2(9), "email" varchar2(21), "groupId" int)

\\

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("id", "f_name", "email")
         VALUES (1, 'john', 'john123@hotmail.com')
    INTO Table1 ("id", "f_name", "email")
         VALUES (2, 'peter', 'peter456@gmail.com')
    INTO Table1 ("id", "f_name", "email")
         VALUES (3, 'johnny', 'john123@hotmail.com')
    INTO Table1 ("id", "f_name", "email")
         VALUES (4, 'peter8', 'peter456@gmail.com')
SELECT * FROM dual

\\

update table1 set "groupId" = 
  (select min(t2."id") as groupId
   from table1 t2
   where table1."email" = t2."email"
   group by t2."email"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephan Lechner, can you please add how to adjust the code with DENSE_RANK to fit the same solution you gave?